# JQuery Isotope - What is the best way to apply margin to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I want to apply perfect margins to my isotoped elements. The problem is that when I declare something like that to my elements:

CSS

```
#container .elements{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 23%;
}
```

JS

```
 $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.elements',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows'
 });
```

There are undesired margins on left and right of the container:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This page might help you: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html In places where I've used isotope, I've used it in combination with a grid system like Bootstrap. In that case, I am giving each element a class of span3, which provides consistent margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using container with negative margins for both left and right

```
#container {
 margin-left: -1%;
 margin-right: -1%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is balancing the inner margin with a container margin:

```
#container .elements{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 //margin-left: 1%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 width: 23%;
}

#container {
  margin-left:1%;
}
```

Another way would be to make your own `lastelement` class and apply it to the last element in each row:

```
#container .elements.lastelement {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be **removing the left margin from the first element of each row**.

You can do this by using **[nth-child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)**.

Your code becomes:

```
#container .elements {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 2%
    width: 24%;
}

#container .elements:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

Please note that I recalculated margins in order to keep things simple.